# Delaying delivery on purpose with Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I use Google Cloud Messaging in my Android app (with the `gcm-server` library) to notify users when something new occurs in the app. I know that it is possible to use a parameter (`DELAY_WHILE_IDLE`) to delay the sending until the phone leaves its idle state.

In my case, I want a user to be able to make some action which would notify the other users with some delay, let's say 6 hours. Is it possible to do such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post delayed message in `Handler` (or set an alarm if you need to do it even when the application is stopped) and send the message in its `run`.

Comment: handler for 6 hours? you must be kidding :)

Comment: Why? Is your phone not able to run for 6 hours? But as I said, if you need to do it even when the application is stopped, you can set an alarm.

Comment: the phone is able to run forever, if the sleep is deactivated (when connected and in debug mode). in all other cases the CPU goes off after some inactivity (30 min or so) and the handler falls asleep along with the CPU. So, alarm is the only option

Comment: Yes, if the phone is asleep, the application is stopped and you need to use an alarm to wake it up. But you can also just wait for the user to turn it on again and the message will be fired then.

Comment: @StenSoft: is it okay to use BroadcastReceiver with Alarm to run the delayed code? Assuming that one user may receive up to 10 delayed notifications daily.